# Accessing Database Meta Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, metadata

Im running into a tough issue. I have a database using Microsoft SQL 2008 and in this database there are many tables. The tables were auto generated and do not have meaningful names. There is one particular table that I need, and I can not seem to find it.

I know what the names of a few of the columns in the table are called. Is there a way I can go through all the tables one at a time looking at the names of the columns and seeing if they match the ones I know.

If they do, then I can look farther into it the table to see if it is the one I am looking for. Does this sound like a good approach to the problem? Is it possible? Any ideas of where to start?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]),
    OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) 
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE name IN ('column 1', 'column 2' 
    /* , ... other columns */);
```

**EDIT** by request, in case the OP meant to identify ALL vs. ANY:

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id), name 
FROM sys.tables AS t
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns
    WHERE name = 'column 1'
    AND [object_id] = t.[object_id]
)
AND EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns
    WHERE name = 'column 2'
    AND [object_id] = t.[object_id]
)
/* ... repeat for other columns ... */
```

Comment: Wouldn't that return tables with `Column 1` or `Column 2` rather than both?

Comment: Yes, but it's a very quick start compared to writing a query that will find a table with *ALL* of the known column names. This should narrow it down pretty quickly...

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to Aaron's answer using Information_schema.columns instead of sys.columns

```
SELECT Table_name
FROM 
      information_schema.columns
WHERE 
      column_name IN ('column 1', 'column 2')
GROUP BY Table_Name
Having COUNT(column_name) = 2
```

See this [Data.SE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1832/sample-for-so-question-7323628) for a working example

Comment: In general I recommend against `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217886/unreliable-information-schema-schema-information-on-sql-server/7310746#7310746

Comment: @Aaron I agree but I like to have as many tools in my tool box as possible. Also in this case (looking at table and column names) I don't see a compelling reason to discount the ANSI standard views

Comment: No it's more about consistency. If you can't use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` for indexes, for example, or richer information about tables or columns even, why use them for a subset of your tasks and have to switch to catalog views for the rest?

Answer (score 0):

With the scripts above, you are limited to SQL wild-carding, which can be pretty limited. You can use [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/) grep to more powerfully search through your database using regular expressions. SchemaCrawler also allows you additional features to to look for tables related by foreign keys, so for example, you can say find me all tables that have a customer address column, along with the tables that refer to these tables. SchemaCrawler is a command-line tool that is bundled with a Microsoft SQL Server database driver.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/)