# mssql INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, information-schema

I have a rails application which imports its own VIEWs.

Now the very first mssql Query fails because the information schema returns 0 rows when being asked for the available columns in a certain table (which rails needs to prep the Objects).

When connecting to the mssql server via studio, i can expand the VIEW and see all columns needed, however querying the information schema like this:

| SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'view'

returns zero rows.

I considered a permissions issue (although i dont get any error, just an empty result set) and have manually granted permissions to the view to the respective user, and it persists.  I also did the query as the admin who actually created the databases and got still 0 rows.

I'm wondering wether:

- there is any obvious reason why this fails?
- MSSQL builds the INFORMATION_SCHEMA on demand, i.e. when i query the SCHEMA.COLUMNS Table, wether mssql uses cached data or actually asks the DB at this point which columns exists?
- if the answer is no: can i rebuild the COLUMNS cache/table?
- does this query at all work for VIEWs?

I did also restart the sql service and look into the events database in search for broken tables, indexes or something.  Events didnt reveal anything (obvious) though.

Anything else that could be missed?

thanks,
 -u

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217886/unreliable-information-schema-schema-information-on-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to get column names for your views...

```
 SELECT C.name 
 FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN sys.views v
 ON c.[object_id] = v.[object_id]
 WHERE v.name = 'Your_View_Name'
```

Reasons why you should'nt use Information schema view, Read this [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views) an article by Aaron Bertrand.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify the full path to the table:

```
select COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_CATALOG = 'dbasename' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' and TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'
```