# Does anyone know of a way to paginate a call to GetSchema from C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, pagination

I'm using the ADO.NET provider function "GetSchema" to fetch meta data out of a Sql Server database (and an Informix system as well) and want to know if there is anyway to paginate the results. I ask because one of the systems has over 3,000 tables (yes, three thousand) and twice that many views and let's not even talk about the stored procedures.
Needless to say, trying to bring down that list in one shot is too much for the VM I have running (a mere 4GB of memory). I'm already aware of the restrictions that can be applied, these are all tables in the "dbo" schema so there isn't much else that I'm aware of for limiting the result set before it gets to my client.

Comment: try `Skip` and `Take` methods using `LINQ`

Comment: If you use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables instead you could write your own query to retrieve partial results

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using GetSchema I suggest to use the more flexible INFORMATION_SCHEMA system views. These views already divide the information about the Tables, StoredProcedures and Views and you can write a specific query to retrieve your data in a paginated way.

For example to retrieve the first 100 rows of table names you could write a query like this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY TABLE_NAME) AS RowNum, *
          FROM      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        ) AS TableWithRowNum
WHERE   RowNum >= 0
    AND RowNum < 100
ORDER BY RowNum
```

Following queries could be easily prepared changing the min and max values used by the query.

The same code could be applied for StoredProcedures (using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'`) or the views using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`

Note, if you are using Sql Server 2012 and later the first query could be rewritten to use this syntax

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

And the C# code could also use parameters for the FIRST (0) and COUNT(100) values

Comment: I would but I am specifically constrained by the fact that the Microsoft information specifically states that the INFORMATION_SCHEMA are NOT to be used as a source of truth as in the following: "** Important ** Do not use INFORMATION_SCHEMA views to determine the schema of an object. The only reliable way to find the schema of a object is to query the sys.objects catalog view." as found on example pages such as [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx). I knew of this already and it still does not answer the question: Can the GetSchema call be paginated?

Comment: Then I think you are out of luck. GetSchema (also with the overload that use the restrictions) doesn't seem to offer an useful way to paginate between the results. Or there is too much data returned or too few results. However your point on 'unrealiability' of INFORMATION_SCHEMA started a search on this that lead me to discover [this interesting answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217886/unreliable-information-schema-schema-information-on-sql-server) from Aaron Bertrand where  the 'unreliability' of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA is discussed and contain some hints to  solve your problem